# freeing memory in C doesn't work

Tags: c, memory, malloc, calloc

I have a problem when i try to free allocated memory in C.

```
int i,j,**redmatrix, **bluematrix, **greenmatrix;
double **weigthMatrix,fsom;
weigthMatrix = (double**) calloc(radius*2+1,sizeof(double*));
redmatrix = (int**) calloc(radius*2+1,sizeof(int*));
bluematrix = (int**) calloc(radius*2+1,sizeof(int*));
greenmatrix = (int**) calloc(radius*2+1,sizeof(int*));
if(weigthMatrix==NULL || redmatrix==NULL || bluematrix==NULL || greenmatrix==NULL){
    printf("%s\n", "Error: probleem met geheugenallocatie");
    exit(1);
}
for(i=0;i<radius*2+2;i++){
    weigthMatrix[i] = (double*) calloc(radius*2+1,sizeof(double));
    redmatrix[i] = (int*) calloc(radius*2+1,sizeof(int));
    bluematrix[i] = (int*) calloc(radius*2+1,sizeof(int));
    greenmatrix[i] = (int*) calloc(radius*2+1,sizeof(int));
    if(weigthMatrix[i]==NULL || redmatrix[i]==NULL || bluematrix[i]==NULL || greenmatrix[i]==NULL){
        printf("%s\n", "Error: probleem met geheugenallocatie");
        exit(1);
    }
}
for(i=0;i<radius*2+1;i++){
    free(weigthMatrix[i]);
    free(redmatrix[i]);
    free(bluematrix[i]);
    free(greenmatrix[i]);
}

free(redmatrix);    //MY PROGRAM CRASHES HERE
free(bluematrix);
free(greenmatrix);
free(weigthMatrix);
free_image(&copyImage);
```

My program crashes when i try to free the top level of my array. I don't know what i am doing wrong. I think I allocated everything right?

Comment: [OMG all those casts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). And all that missing whitespace.

Comment: I think it's an array overrun -- `radius*2+1` in the `calloc` calls vs. `radius*2+2` in the loops. Why don't you use the same value throughout?

Comment: Oops, that was wrong in the answer, but i did write it correctly in my code, so that isn't the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reserve space for `radius*2+1` elements

```
redmatrix = (int**) calloc(radius*2+1,sizeof(int*));
```

But then you fill and free arrays with `radius*2+2` elements

```
for(i=0;i<radius*2+2;i++){
    redmatrix[i] = (int*) calloc(radius*2+1,sizeof(int));

for(i=0;i<radius*2+2;i++){
    free(redmatrix[i]);
    ...
```

change to

```
for(i=0;i<radius*2+1;i++){
    redmatrix[i] = (int*) calloc(radius*2+1,sizeof(int));
    ...

for(i=0;i<radius*2+1;i++){
    free(redmatrix[i]);
    ...
```

And please, don't cast `malloc`